# Avoid to write '\n' to the last line of a file in python

Tags: python, file, line

I'm writing multiple lines to a new file (could be up to several GB), like this:

```
for item in record:
    output_pass.write('%s\n' %item)
```

However, I got a blank line due to the '\n' of my last record, such as:

Start of the file

```
record111111

reocrd222222

record333333

---a blank line---
```

End of a file

Since my file is large, I would not want to read the file again. So, is there an easy way to prevent this, or easy way to remove the last '\n' from the file?

My solution:

Thanks for all the help!

I think I will not load the entire file to the memeory, since it may get very huge.

I actually solve this by first write the first record, then write the rest line in a loop. I put '\n' in the front so it won't appear on the last line.

But Jonathan is right. I actually have now problem with the '\n' in the last line, majorly it is my OCD.

Here is my code:

```
rec_first = parser_fastq.next() #This is just an iterator of my file
output.write('%s' %('>'+rec_first[0].strip('@')))
output.write('\n%s' %(rec_first[1])) #I put '\n' in the front

count = 1

#Write the rest of lines
for rec_fastq in parser_fastq:
    output.write('\n%s' %('>'+rec_fastq[0].strip('@')))
    output.write('\n%s' %(rec_fastq[1]))
    count += 1
    print 'Extracting %ith record in %s ...' %(count, fastq_name) + '\b'*100,

output.close()
```

print '\n%i records were wrote to %s' % (count, fasta_name)

Comment: Are you sure that it's really a problem? Actually, most text-based tools (e.g. most Unix utils) *expect* to have a newline at the end of the file (i.e. the newline is intended as a line *terminator*, not as a *separator*).

Comment: Do you really want all those other blank lines between items in your output file? It looks the each is ending up with _two_ `'\n'` characters.

Comment: Is the file huge because a single `record` has that much data in it, or are you processing many records that could total up to a size that big? The answer to that will likely affect what answer is truly the best for your needs.

Answer (score 14):

This should be a simple solution:

```
for item in record[:-1]:
    output_pass.write("%s\n" % item)
output_pass.write("%s" % record[-1])
```

Using `join` is *not* recommended if you said the file was large - it will create the entire file content string in memory.

Comment: upv for educating as to why `join` is not recommended

Comment: For lists slice expression [:] creates a copy of that list, so you waste memory too.

Comment: @Bhargav: Whether avoiding `join` is necessary or not currently isn't clear from the question since we don't really know how many items there might be in a `record` nor how big the string representation might of each might be. Like so many questions here, the parameters of the problem are unclear.

Comment: @martineau Sir, thus using `join` is also not wrong?

Comment: @Bhargav: My point was that it _might_ work OK, but we don't have any way of knowing whether it would or not without additional information from the OP.

Comment: This does not work for `io.read or io.write: TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Answer (score 2):

This requires constant additional memory:

```
for i, item in enumerate(record):
    if i>0: 
        output_pass.write('\n')
    output_pass.write('%s' %item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them first and then `write` as in

```
item = '\n'.join(record)
output_pass.write('%s' %item)
```

**Note**

If your list, i.e. `record` doesn't contain strings, then as Martinaeu has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158403/avoid-to-write-n-to-the-last-line-of-a-file-in-python/28158435?noredirect=1#comment44723428_28158435) you will have to map it to a `str` that is, `'\n'.join(map(str, record))` before you write to file. (In py2)

Comment: OP is talking about a multi-gigabyte file, in that case this is definitely a bad idea (it creates the whole string in memory first).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks. Do inform me if it is completely wrong, so that I can delete it

Comment: It's not wrong *per se*, but in this case it would become a performance nightmare (not only you are creating the whole string in memory, but the useless `'%s' % item` is going to create yet another copy of it).

Comment: Bhargav (& @Matteo): This probably won't work, not because `record` might be huge (although it could be and that might be an issue), but since it's probably not a sequence of strings (but again we don't know that for sure), which is what the `join()` method requires its first argument to be -- so, as written, the most the likely result would be `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, xxx found`. That could be easily fixed by using `map(str, record)` assuming `record` isn't prohibitively large (and converting each of its items to strings isn't either).

Comment: @martineau Thank you Sir. I have edited the answer to include your thoughts. Thanks again

Comment: Er, I was thinking more along the lines of `'\n'.join(map(str, record))` because, among other reasons you would be permanently clobbering the value of `record` with something only needed temporarily. Actually `output_pass.write('\n'.join(map(str, record)))` might be even better. Also, please stop calling me "Sir", such formalities aren't needed here. `;-)`

Comment: P.S. `r'\n'` would be wrong and whether to do this has nothing to with py2.

Comment: @martineau Thank you ... (I call you Sir as a mark of respect and not formality ;) ... We have been taught to address every one with a title snce our young age. Apart from that I am too young to talk directly )

Comment: That `r` was a remnant from the previous `record`

Answer (score 1):

do you try with some counter?  like:

```
record = [str(x) for x in range(10)]
print record

import sys
output_pass=sys.stdout

counter = 0

while counter != (len(record))-1:
   output_pass.write("%s\n" % record[counter])
   counter += 1
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work? Even assuming that `record` is a list (it may not be, from the code it just looks like an enumerable object) your code just prints it backwards skipping the last element, always leaving the newline anyway. http://ideone.com/UvNCsJ

Comment: This prints the contents of the file in reverse order. So you will need to write another code to do the parse in the other direction ;)

Comment: @MatteoItalia  yes, Sorry... I do not know when I was thinking; take your code and "rearrange"

Comment: @BhargavRao Now the code work fine without the last line :P  http://ideone.com/h8mfa5

Answer (score 1):

The following would write all but the last item in `record` with newlines very quickly and then the final one without it. It will do so without requiring much additional memory.

(For Python 3 use `range` instead of `xrange`)

```
item = iter(record)
for _ in xrange(len(record)-1):
    output_pass.write('%s\n' % next(item))

output_pass.write('%s' % next(item))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Sir, I undeleted my answer hoping some stray programmer might find it useful. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make a definition to write a file away.

```
def writeFile(value): 
    open('file.txt', 'a') as file 
    file.write(value)
    file.write('\n')
```

Then you call this definition to write data in the file. 
"value" will be in one line.

```
writeFile('HelloWorld')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should worry about a trailing \n.  It's beneficial in a lot of scenarios (like if you want to add another line), and it's even recommended as part of the flake8 python source profiler.

@Amir's answer will work for avoiding writing the newline.

If you want to remove the last line, you can just write the entire file as-is, and then create a file object to use `seek()` + `read()` to test the last character, and then `seek()` and `truncate()` to remove it -- calling `read` after `seek` will require a second `seek`.

This is largely explained in this Q&A:

- [Python - Remove very last character in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857352/python-remove-very-last-character-in-file)

Answer (score 0):

it should work.
use .replace("\n", "") for the last item in the list.

```
for item in items:
    print item[0], line[1].replace("\n", "")
```