# Python Scrapy Pipeline Edit Last Item?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm using a pipeline in Scrapy to output the scraped results into a JSON file. The pipeline places a comma after each item that is scraped however, I want to drop the comma for the last item. Is there a way to do that?

This is the pipeline:

```
class ExamplePipeline(object):
def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.file = open('example.json', 'w')
    self.file.write("[")

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.file.write("]")
    self.file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    line = json.dumps(
        dict(item),
        indent = 4,
        sort_keys = True,
        separators = (',', ': ')
    ) + ",\n"
    self.file.write(line)
    return item
```

And the sample output looks like:

```
[
{
    "item1": "example",
    "item2": "example"
},
{
    "item1": "example",
    "item2": "example"
},
]
```

What is the python method to find the last item and not give it a comma separator? I thought I could do something like `if item[-1] ...` but I can't get that working.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should checkout inbuild scrapy exporters. You can simply write `scrapy crawl spider -o output.json` https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#jsonitemexporter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply this to your pipeline, you'll have to seek back in your file and delete that comma:

See related [Python - Remove very last character in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857352/python-remove-very-last-character-in-file)

```
class ExamplePipeline(object):

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        # go back 2 characters: \n and ,
        self.file.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
        # cut trailing data
        self.file.truncate()
        # save
        self.file.write("]")
        self.file.close()
```

Comment: Fantastic. I was nowhere near approaching the problem like that; Thank you Granitosaurus

Comment: Also, **note to anyone else using this solution** - you also need to `import os` for it to work