# Python 3: Idiomatic way to delete last char in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, readfile, truncate

Is there an idiomatic way to do this? I just upgraded from Python 2 to Python 3 and I'm trying to port my script, and I gotta say I'm not impressed. From what I can tell, my code gets to go

from this

```
# Not allowed by Python 3 anymore without being in binary mode.
card_names_file.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
if card_names_file.read() == ',':
    card_names_file.truncate()
```

to this

```
# Go to end of file just to get position index. lawl.
card_names_file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
# Create a temporary just to store said index. More lawl.
eof = card_names_file.tell()
# Index one from the back. ugh. w/e, that's fine.
card_names_file.seek(eof - 1, os.SEEK_SET)

# Oh wait, .read() will advance my pointer. Oh hey Python 3 doesn't let me
# use .peek() either. Fantastic. I'll have to read this...
if card_names_file.read() == ',':
    # Then go back to where I was by indexing from front AGAIN
    card_names_file.seek(eof - 1, os.SEEK_SET)
    # Then remove last character.
    card_names_file.truncate()
```

This is the dumbest code I've almost ever seen and I've spent 2 and a half hours so far trying to delete a character from the back of a file, and this looks like a hack.

The alternative is that I have code that looks like this

```
# open file
with open(file, a+)
    # do stuff

# open same file
with open(file, w+b)
    # do different stuff
```

But I can't actually get that to work either.

Comment: Your first snippet is b0rked. The `card_names_file.truncate()` does nothing because you're already at the end of the file.

Comment: I'm also fairly sure that the `seek` function always operates on bytes, so your code never really worked in python 2 either.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857352/python-remove-very-last-character-in-file

Comment: @aran It definitely worked, so maybe in Pyhton 2 .read didn't advance the pointer.

@ snakecharmerb, I've definitely read that entire thread, it didn't answer my question. You'll notice that the selected answer doesn't work in Python 3 at all, and one of them i is like 30 lines of code. No thanks.

Comment: It may look like the code works because your file is using an encoding where a comma is encoded as a single byte. If there is an encoding where the comma is represented by more than 1 byte, or another multi-byte character *contains* a byte that looks like a comma, your code will most certainly not work correctly.

Comment: That's true, you have a point with the encoding part. In my particular use case though, I've guaranteed that all of my characters are exactly 1 byte. But you are correct, that wouldn't work in a generic sense as part of a library API or something where who knows what you could be parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Underlying buffer does have a `peek()` method you were looking for, so:

```
f = open('FILE', 'a+')
f.seek(f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) - 1)
# or with the same effect you can also:
os.lseek(f.fileno(), -1, os.SEEK_END)
# Actually in append mode we could just seek by -1 from where we are
# (cursor at the end after opening)
f.tell()  # just to see...
f.buffer.peek(1)
f.tell()  # ...still where we were
```

Alternatively, you could also use [`os.pread()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pread). For instance:

```
os.pread(f.fileno(), 1, os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size - 1)
```

It's not very idiomatic as in relying on higher level abstraction accessing files, but I'd [invoke](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3): *"Although practicality beats purity."*

Comment: This works and its pretty much the same amount of code as my Python 2 impl. Thank you so much! I was unaware of the underlying buffer. Thanks again!