# How to delete last n characters of .txt file without having to re-write all the other characters

Tags: python-3.x

I have a massive `.txt` file, and I want to read it one line at a time, and if I find a line which meets a certain condition, I want to go into that file and change the last `n` characters of that line only.

The only way I've seen of doing that is to re-write all the lines to a new .txt, while changing the lines you want to change.

This is how I envision my desired logic would look.

```
for line in infile:
    if 'ABC' in line:
        infile.#here would come the code to replace characters
```

I don't think `with open()` has this functionality - or does it? Is there a library which does what I describe?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18857381/5478462

Comment: This seems like exactly what I want! 

Just wanted to make sure that 1) UTF-8 encoding is single-byte and 2) that when I create a .txt file via `with open('name.txt', 'x')` in python, it is with UTF-8 encoding. 

Thanks for the answer, feel a bit bad that I wasn't able to find that thread :D!