# How to add an element to a list?

Tags: python, json, list

From this..

```
data = json.loads(urlopen('someurl').read())
```

...I will get:

```
{'list': [{'a':'1'}]}
```

I want to add `{'b':'2'}` into the `list`.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I would do this:

```
data["list"].append({'b':'2'})
```

so simply you are adding an object to the list that is present in "data"

Answer (score 9):

Elements are added to list using [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> data = {'list': [{'a':'1'}]}
>>> data['list'].append({'b':'2'})
>>> data
{'list': [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]}
```

If you want to add element to a specific place in a list (i.e. to the beginning), use `insert()` instead:

```
>>> data['list'].insert(0, {'b':'2'})
>>> data
{'list': [{'b': '2'}, {'a': '1'}]}
```

After doing that, you can assemble JSON again from dictionary you modified:

```
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"list": [{"b": "2"}, {"a": "1"}]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

myDict = {'dict': [{'a': 'none', 'b': 'none', 'c': 'none'}]}
test = json.dumps(myDict)
print(test)
```

**{"dict": [{"a": "none", "b": "none", "c": "none"}]}**

```
myDict['dict'].append(({'a': 'aaaa', 'b': 'aaaa', 'c': 'aaaa'}))
test = json.dumps(myDict)
print(test)
```

**{"dict": [{"a": "none", "b": "none", "c": "none"}, {"a": "aaaa", "b": "aaaa", "c": "aaaa"}]}**