# Python JSON replace value in specific line

Tags: python, json

I've been experimenting with python for a while and just ran into an issue I can't find an answer to. Just started building a small 'banking' console app and it's "database" is in JSON file. Now I added a command called 'transfer' which should transfer 'funds' from one user_id to another.
JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "user_id": "u111111111",
        "pin": "2222",
        "balance": "50800"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "u123456789",
        "pin": "1234",
        "balance": "0"
    }
]
}
```

Last thing I tried was something like this and got completely stuck.

```
user_database = 'accounts.json'
    ujf = json.loads(open(user_database, 'r+').read())

    for element in ujf['users']:
        if (element['user_id'] == str(user_id_one)):
            element['balance'] = str(user_one_new_balance)
        else:
            pass
```

How do I update the 'balance' value for user_id u111111111 and for user_id u123456789 and save the file, without creating a new file?

Comment: Having a JSON for a database is a poor idea. By the way you have to handle a ledger and compute the balance from this ledger based on initial values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save Python dictionary to file, and update it periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187250/save-python-dictionary-to-file-and-update-it-periodically)

Comment: It looks like you already solved your problem.  Now you just need to dump the `dict` back to a JSON file.  Have you looked up how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First import JSON module:

```
import json
```

Then load the JSON file as dictionary:

```
d = json.load(r'PATH')
```

Then inside the loop you can assign `user['balance']` to whatever you like, e.g. 8 here:

```
for user in d['users']:
     if user['user_id'] in ['u111111111','u123456789']:
         user['balance'] = 8
```

Then dump back:

```
json.dump(d,(open(r'PATH','w')))
```