# Python: Adding element to list of a file without read and write each time

Tags: python, list, file

```
import json

# define list with values
basicList = [1, 2, 3, ..., 10000000]

# open output file for writing
with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as filehandle:  
    json.dump(basicList, filehandle)
```

I created a very long list and wrote it to a file. How can I now add a single element to the file without reading and rewriting the whole file?

Comment: You can't, not without careful re-writing of every value *after* the inserted value.

Comment: use append open('listfile.txt', 'a')

Comment: Pick a different file format if that's an issue; JSON is not suited to incremental updates.

Comment: @aman5319: that will **not** do what the OP wants. You can't just append to a JSON document, that breaks the JSON format.

Comment: I am not dependant on JSON format. Can you provide a code example?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not a duplicate since this question contains the specific constraint of *not* reading / writing the whole file content each time an element is added. None of the answers addresses this issue.

Comment: @a_guest: yes, it does cover that. Specifically, the [answer by SingleNegationElimination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994577/100297).