# How to append in a json file in python

Tags: json

I am new in coding and I am trying to get data in powerBI with JSON file, I tried the following but was not able to do it correctly..it gives error like multiple json root element

```
 with open(payload_nkstr,'a') as fp:
                json.dump(payload_nk,fp)
```

below is my value-

```
{
    "GlobalRunTime": 1.2487333333333333,
    "GlobalMinimumRemainingLife": -1.1,
    "GlobalMinimumConsumedLife": 6.40551647627992,
    "ShaftRemainingLife": -1.1,
    "ShaftConsumedLife": 6.40551647627992,
    "GearRemainingLife": 0.8,
    "GearConsumedLife": 0.6109182273971371,
    "BearingRemainingLife": 1209.38204778207,
    "BearingConsumedLife": 0.0003628380073003079,
    "timestep": "2019-12-11_09:19"
}{
    "GlobalRunTime": 1.2570333333333332,
    "GlobalMinimumRemainingLife": -1.1,
    "GlobalMinimumConsumedLife": 6.44821647627992,
    "ShaftRemainingLife": -1.1,
    "ShaftConsumedLife": 6.44821647627992,
    "GearRemainingLife": 0.8,
    "GearConsumedLife": 0.6131359924269855,
    "BearingRemainingLife": 1081.5089585430167,
    "BearingConsumedLife": 0.0004084093807551296,
    "timestep": "2019-12-11_09:22"
}
```

Comment: I think that you might find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994442/how-to-append-data-to-a-json-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append data to a json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994442/how-to-append-data-to-a-json-file)