# Append data to json file if not in it already

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a .json file which I would like to append data to. But only if this string is not in the .json file already.

JSON File:

```
[{"filename":"file1"}, {"filename":"file2"}, {"filename":"file3"}]
```

End result JSON File:

```
[{"filename":"file1"}, {"filename":"file2"}, {"filename":"file3"}, {"filename":"file4"}]
```

I currently have this:

```
with open('gdrivefiles.json', 'r') as f:
     filenameslist = json.load(f)    #Loads the .json file into a string (If I'm right)
for distro in filenameslist:
     filenames = distro["filename"]  #Gets a list of all the filenames

if name in filenames:
   print("yes")                      #If name is in the list of filenames print 'yes'
else:
   print("no")                       #If name is in the list of filenames print 'no'
```

(This code is put in a for-loop, so it will run this code for every new value of `name`)

How would I add `name` (`{"filename":"name"}`) in the json file if it is not in it already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append data to a json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994442/how-to-append-data-to-a-json-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
import json

new_file = {"filename":"name"}

data = json.load(open("data.json"))
if not any([new_file['filename'] == x['filename'] for x in data]):
    data.append(new_file)

    json.dump(data, open("data.json","w"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! I can add any code to perform when it isn't already in the list right? And if I would want to perform code if it **IS** in the list I can just remove the `not`?

Comment: Yeah, if you only want to run code if your filename is already in the list, just remove the `not` operator, and put your code inside the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create the data structure when writing back:

```
import json

name = "file4"
with open('gdrivefiles.json', 'r') as f:
    filenameslist = json.load(f)

filenames = [distro["filename"] for distro in filenameslist]

if name in filenames:
    print("yes")                      #If name is in the list of filenames print 'yes'
else:
    print("no")                       #If name is in the list of filenames print 'no'
    filenames.append(name)

#  write filenames back to file as list of dicts!
with open('gdrivefiles.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps([{'filename': name} for name in filenames]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

new_object = {"filename":"file5"}

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    if new_object not in data: 
      data.append(new_object)        
      json_file.close()

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(data, outfile)
   outfile.close()
```