# How can you add an object into json through python

Tags: python, json

I am making a simple sandwich-logging app in Python and I want to add an object like this:

```
"Sandwich A" : {
    "name" : "Sandwich A"
    "contents" : [
        "bread",
        "mayo",
        "bread"
    ]
}
```

Into this JSON file, right next to Sandwich B

```
{
    "Sandwiches" : {

        "Sandwich B" : {
            "name" : "Sandwich B"
            "contents" : [
                "bread",
                "butter",
                "bread"
]
        }
    }
}
```

through Python.

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```py
import json

with open('Example.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    data["Sandwiches"][name] = {"name" : name, "contents" : contents}
```

Update: I tried this simpler version of my bigger app, but it still doesn't work

```py
import json

def SandwichSteps():
    contents = []
    layer = input("    ")
    if layer == "end":
        return contents
    else:
        contents.append(layer)
        SandwichSteps()


with open('Sandos.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    contents = SandwichSteps()
    name = input("name    ")

    data["Sandos"][name] = {"name" : name, "contents" : contents}
```

could you please explain what went wrong?

Comment: Please see [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file).

Comment: This should work, if you have values for the variables `name` and `contents`

Comment: I do but it doesn't add it to the file

Comment: I don't want to rewrite the file, I just want to add to it.

Comment: You've not said what went wrong

Comment: @SiHa It didn't add to the json file.

Comment: Well, no - You've not written the file out, how could it? You open the file, read it, change the data and *do nothing else*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python read JSON file and modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035762/python-read-json-file-and-modify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Dump to string

The json.dumps() function puts a python object into a json string.

```
jsonStr = json.dumps(myobject.__dict__)
```

More info: https://pythonexamples.org/convert-python-class-object-to-json/

### Dump to file

To dump the json to a file, you could do this:

```
def create_json():
    json_string = json.dumps([ob.__dict__ for ob in stList])
    with open("./data/student.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(json_string)
```

This code takes a list of objects, but you can also call the json.dumps() function like in the previous paragraph.

### Add to existing file

I found some info on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994442/how-to-append-data-to-a-json-file)

Comment: But how do you add it to a file?

Comment: But how can you _add_ it to a file? I didn't want to _rewrite_ the file.