# parse json from txt file not working in python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract data from txt file in python which is a json dump. But I am getting **JSONDecode Error**

This is how I am adding json response into the file

```
repo=requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=params).json()
if repo:
    with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
        json.dump(repo, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    continue
else:
    break
```

this is my json structure

```
[
    {
        "login": "asu",
        "login_name": "heylo"
    },
    {
        "login": "sr9",
        "login_name": "heylo"
    }
],
[
    {
        "login": "tokuda109",
        "login_name": "mojombo"
    },
    {
        "login": "svallory",
        "login_name": "mojombo"
    }
]
```

this is I am trying to extract

```
with open('data.txt') as fd:
    json_data = json.load(fd)
    pprint(json_data)
```

Comment: If you're getting JSONDecodeError, then you're not loading correct JSON.

Comment: @AKX this issues occur when I am appending the data in the file, not occuring when I am writing into the file

Comment: By appending to the file, you've created invalid JSON. `json.load` does not allow reading concatenated JSON structures like that. You might want to consider https://jsonlines.org/ – i.e. exactly one JSON structure per line, and then loading with a loop over the lines.

Comment: could you please share requests arguments? I wanna repeat the procedure

Comment: then how would i append json objects into the file

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra this will help [How to append data to a json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994442/how-to-append-data-to-a-json-file)

Comment: @deadshot yes, I have appended json into the txt file

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili , I am extracting data from github url

this is the example url 

https://api.github.com/users/sferik/followers?per_page=100&page=1

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, just concatenating JSON objects into a file one after another does not make a file that's valid JSON (and that could be parsed as a single JSON object).

The minimal better format is JSON Lines, https://jsonlines.org/ , that is a file of lines that are each a JSON document.

You can create such a file by appending to a file while ensuring `indent` is off when dumping JSON:

```
with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
    print(json.dumps(repo, sort_keys=True), file=f)
```

Using `print()` ensures a trailing newline.

Then, you can load the data with e.g.

```
with open('data.txt') as fd:
    json_data = [json.loads(line) for line in fd if line.strip()]
```

If the current file of concatenated JSON documents is important to you, you could try and repair it with a hack like wrapping the file's contents with `[` and `]` and adding a comma between otherwise malformed concatenated documents, but this is not quite guaranteed to work.

```
with open('data.txt') as fd:
    fixed_json_data = json.loads("[" + fd.read().replace("}{", "},{") + "]")
```

Comment: not working json decode error expecting line 2 column 1

Comment: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2103 column 1 (char 111481]

Comment: i have made little changes in the json format

Comment: Well, if you've made little changes to the format, then I'm sure you can figure out how to parse it. It's very hard to help without seeing your actual data.

Comment: I have shared the actual data , 

also i have  fixed_json_data = json.loads("[" + fd.read().replace("}{", "},{") + "],") or 
 fixed_json_data = json.loads("[" + fd.read().replace("}{", "},{") + "]" + ",")
with both cases its not working

Comment: The JSON structure you've edited into your post is still not valid JSON. You would need to wrap it in one more set of brackets for it to parse as a single array.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [How to append data to a json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994442/how-to-append-data-to-a-json-file), using `a` mode is not a good choice, I think it is better to append fetched data to the available list in `data.txt` manually like this:

```
import json
import requests


def read_content():  # reads and returns the available list in data.txt
    try:
        with open('data.txt') as fd:
            json_data = json.load(fd)
    except:
        json_data = []  # handle the first write, when the file does not exist
    return json_data


url = 'https://api.github.com/users/sferik/followers?per_page=100&page=1'
repo = requests.get(url).json()  # repo is a list

if repo:
    available_content = read_content()  # read available list in data.txt
    available_content.extend(repo)  # extend new list to the end of available list
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:  # write again, the mode is 'w'
        json.dump(repo, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: this approach is not good because there are 10 million objects every time it appends it will select also